# JavaSE6 Clone class with mutable instance variable

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong here?  Teaching myself Java from Murach's Java SE6.  Working on an excercise over implementing the Cloneable Interface.  When I run the app that has the main() utilizing these classes I get this error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: LineItem cannot be cast to Product
    at LineItem.clone(LineItem.java:73)
    at LineItemCloneApp.main(LineItemCloneApp.java:23)
C:\Users\Jermell\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
//****LineItem.java*********
public class LineItem implements Cloneable
{
    private Product product;
private int quantity;
private double total;

// constructor and a bunch of get and set methods

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        // special clone process to deal with mutable instant variable Product
        LineItem li = (LineItem) super.clone();
        Product p = (Product) this.getProduct().clone();
        li.setProduct(p);
        return li;            
    }
}
```

******Differt .jave file in same directory*******

```
//*****Product.java*******
public class Product implements Cloneable
{
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    // constructor and a bunch of get and set methods

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Please post a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Something has been simplified out too much. The class cast exception should not be thrown from the coded provided.